# Make tmux start with fish shell

Tags: tmux

I have both zsh and fish shell installed.

When I run tmux, it start with zsh.

[image]

I want it start with fish shell.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your `tmux.conf` and add this:

```
# use /full/path/to/fish if it's not in $PATH
set -g default-command fish
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html),

`default-command shell-command` is used to set the command for new windows. And `default-shell path` is used to specify the default shell.

```
set-option -g default-shell /usr/bin/fish
```

Comment: note that `default-command` can override `default-shell` so make sure `default-command` is empty (the default).